# area of rotated squares on top of each other

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've got a problem of calculating 'visible' areas of rotated squares on top of each other.

Say I have two squares $s_0$ and $s_1$ on top of each other. They have the same side length and same center. The top one, $s_1$, is rotated some angle v with respect to the bottom square, $s_0$. Thus, there are only 4 parts of the bottom rectangle $s_0$ 'visible'.

I can calculate this area with basic trigonometry.

Now my question is what happens when there are many squares, each rotated with angle $v$ from each other (i.e. square $n$ is rotated angle $nv$ with respect to the bottom square)? What is the visible area of the bottom square $s_0$ in this case? What about square $s_n$ (assuming there are say $N$ total squares)?

Is this even possible to calculate?

Comment: You'd have to find a relationship between the angle $v$ and the amount of area gained/lost when adding another square with a rotation $2v$

Comment: Are you assuming a common axis of rotation through the centre of the first square? And are you assuming that $nv\lt \frac \pi2$ ?

Comment: David: yes, the axis of rotation is the same and nv < pi / 2.